# Why are elements in set not in order in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello this is Min Su First, sorry for my poor English. I want somebody help me. As I know, set type doesn't have order but if set(Iterable) for example, set([3,4,1,2]) is ran , result will be {1,2,3,4} (elements in set are in order)

And this is my code.

```
def xxxxx():
    maxnum = 1000000000000
    lst = []
    lst.append(2)
    for i in range(1000000):
        if i>1:
            n=i
            t=n+1
            temp = n*t
            lst.append(temp)
            while True:
                temp =temp*(t+1)
                if temp>maxnum:
                    break
                lst.append(temp)
                t+=1
    temp1 = set(lst)
    temp2 = list(temp1)
    temp2.sort()
    return temp1

{
2,
 393847242756,
 6,
 7233077256,
 165140234250,
 12,
 29360142,
 42670751760,
 102225674256,
 345388351506,
 20,
 8501854230,
 24,
....}
```

This is what I got but this isn't what I expected because elements in set are not in order. I expected something like `{2,6,12,20,24,....}`
So my question is why has this happened?

Comment: sets are unordered, you already answered your own question...

Comment: You say "As I know, set type doesn't have order but if set(Iterable) for example, set([3,4,1,2]) is ran , result will be {1,2,3,4} (elements in set are in order)". Since set is unordered I'm not sure where you've got the expectation that it should appear in a guaranteed order when instantiated from a list and printed. Where in the docs does it say this?

Comment: use `temp1 = set(lst)` as `temp1 = sorted(set(lst))`

Comment: Set elements are in *arbitrary* order. Just because *some* are in numerical order does not mean they all are.

Comment: i thought that although set doesn't have order so it doesn't have index, set elements are always in numerical order.
Now i got it thank you so much everyone~~

Answer (score 1):

write the code like this

```
temp1 = sorted(set(lst))
temp2 = list(temp1)
temp2.sort()
return temp1
```

Output -:

```
[2,
 6,
 12,
 20,
 24,
 30,
 42,
 56,
 60,
 72,
 90,
 110,
 120,
 132,
 156,
 182,
.
.
.
.]
```